# UIPanGestureRecognizer with UIPageViewController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am using a UIPageViewController to display certain content. I want to be able to display additional content when the user pulls down on the page using a UIPanGestureRecognizer. I can't seem to figure out what I should add my gesture recognizer to such that it does not cancel any of the pageviewcontroller's actions.

Answer (score 0):

One of the apps I worked on has functionality similar to this.  It shows a full-screen UIPageViewController, but if the user drags down on a ribbon on the top right corner, it will slide the whole thing down to reveal a view behind (for settings and other stuff).

I think your problem is that the built-in gesture recognizers are for the page turns.  So what you'd want to do is either have something to drag on (such as the ribbon on the top left in my app) that will have its own gestures.  OR you can iterate through the gesture recognizers that are assigned to UIPageViewController and get the one that matches the PanGesture, then override it with your own functionality to either delegate the event to the UIPageViewController or do the slide down, based on the type of pan.

Hope that helps.